# Scala return value from match case

Tags: scala, scope, pattern-matching, return-value

So here is my code:

```
val regexMeter = """^\s*(\d+,*\d+)\s*[m]\s*$""".r
val regexCentimeter = """^\s*(\d+,*\d+)\s*cm\s*$""".r
val regexDecimeter = """^\s*(\d+,*\d+)\s*dm\s*$""".r
val regexMillimeter = """^\s*(\d+,*\d+)\s*mm\s*$""".r

val height = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please insert the height of your shape:")
height match {
  case regexMeter(value) => val newValue = value.toDouble*100
  case regexCentimeter(value) => val newValue = value.toDouble
  case regexDecimeter(value) => val newValue = value.toDouble*10
  case regexMillimeter(value) => val newValue = value.toDouble/10
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

So the thing is my input is for example : "21m" and its fetching only the 21 and if its the regex matching with meters its assigning it to the `val newValue` and doing some stuff with it.
But when I now want to print that value `newValue` it says that it cant find the value?
How can I return this val outside from this match case?

Comment: Just remove the assignment part `val newValue =` and the result of the pattern matching will be the returned value (if nothing after in your function).

Comment: okay I will try that solution too, thanks! 
Edit: It does not work! It is till taking the value from the input line...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Scala, almost everything is an expression and returns a value, including pattern matches:

```
val newValue = height match {
    case regexMeter(value) => value.toDouble*100
    case regexCentimeter(value) => value.toDouble
    case regexDecimeter(value) => value.toDouble*10
    case regexMillimeter(value) => value.toDouble/10
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```